# PHPMyAdmin, SQL Syntax Error Error check the manual

Tags: php, mariadb

```
//Create Table
$CreateTable = "USE `GadgetStore3`;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Credential' (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    class VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    mark INT(3)NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(7)NOT NULL)";

if ($conn->query($CreateTable) === TRUE) {
echo "Table created successfully <br>";}
else {
  echo "Error: " . $conn->error . "<br>";
}
```

Tried changing and tweaking some of the back-commas.

Used the same code and pasted it on PHPMyAdmin it works but when I run the program, this error comes out :

> "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Credential' ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREME...' at line 2